# Looping through 2 vectors of different dimension in R

Tags: r, loops, string-comparison, fuzzy-comparison

I have two character vectors a, b with different dimensions. I have to take each element in a and compare with all elements in b and note the element if there is a close match. For matching I'm using agrepl function.

Following is the sample data

```
a <- c("US","Canada","United States","United States of America")
b <- c("United States","U.S","United States","Canada", "America", "Spain")
```

Following is the code that I'm using to match. Please help me how to avoid for loop as my real data has more 900 and 5000 records respectively

```
for(i in 1:4)
{
    for(j in 1:6)
    {
      bFlag <- agrepl(a[i],b[j],  max.distance = 0.1,ignore.case = TRUE)

      if(bFlag)
      {
        #Custom logic
      }
      else 
      {
        #Custom logic
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a double loop, since `agrepl`'s second argument accepts vectors of length >= 1. So you could do something like:

```
lapply(a, function(x) agrepl(x, b, max.distance = 0.1, ignore.case = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

You can add some custom logic inside the `lapply` call if needed, but that's not specified in the question so I'll just leave the output as a list of `logical`s.

If you want indices (of TRUEs) instead of logicals, you can use `agrep` instead of `agrepl`:

```
lapply(a, function(x) agrep(x, b, max.distance = 0.1,ignore.case = TRUE))

# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 6
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 3
# 
# [[4]]
# integer(0)
```

If you only want the first TRUE index, you can use:

```
sapply(a, function(x) agrep(x, b, max.distance = 0.1,ignore.case = TRUE)[1])
#  US                   Canada            United States United States of America 
#   1                        4                        1                       NA
```

Comment: Thank you...!!! I'm expecting a corresponding index of the element in vector b if its true. First true index is sufficient

Comment: @Naveen, if you want indices, just use `agrep` instead of `agrepl` in the example